# Filtering on grouped variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
          Group=c('A','A','A','B','B','B'),
          Activity = c('Act1','Act4', 'Act3','Act1', 'Act2','Act3')
        )
```

I want to filter for those groups only which contain both activities `Act1` and `Act2`. The following code returns zero values:

```
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% filter(Activity == 'Act1' & Activity == 'Act2')
```

If I use `df %>% group_by(Group) %>% filter(Activity %in% c('Act1' , 'Act2') )`, it also returns group A, which I don't need.

How can I get only those groups that necessarily contain **both** the activities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap it `any`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter(any(Activity == 'Act1')  & any(Activity == 'Act2'))

# Group Activity
#  <fct> <fct>   
#1 B     Act1    
#2 B     Act2    
#3 B     Act3
```

Using the same logic in base R option `ave`

```
df[as.logical(ave(df$Activity, df$Group, 
              FUN = function(x) any(x == 'Act1')  & any(x == 'Act2'))), ]
```

---

You can get the same result using `all`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter(all(c("Act1", "Act2") %in% Activity))
```

and similar with `ave`

```
df[as.logical(ave(df$Activity, df$Group, 
           FUN = function(x) all(c("Act1", "Act2") %in% x))),]


# Group Activity
#4     B     Act1
#5     B     Act2
#6     B     Act3
```

Comment: thanks! Had no idea about the `any` and `ave` functions.

Comment: a slight problem...Was looking at filtering for only the two values (`Act1` and `Act2`). Your solution is also returning `Act3` for group `B`. Any way of overcoming this?

Comment: @Dhiraj The most immediate way I could think of is to add an additional condition `df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  filter(all(c("Act1", "Act2") %in% Activity) & Activity %in% c("Act1", "Act2"))
` should give what you want.