# How to filter rows based on multiple criteria in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df1:

```
ID   ID2    Code 
22   11     994
22   28     996
22   35     999
22   36     997
22   40     998
24   17     991
24   18     998
24   20     998
52   31     991
52   39     991
80   45     994
87   66     998
90   67     995
81   62     991
81   63     991
81   64     990
90   69     997
90   70     998
94   74     994
97   82     996
```

Each ID is an individual person. I get rid of people that ever have a Code that is not either a '990, 991, 992 or 998". For example, ID 22, has a code 994 so I would like to get rid of them. ID 24 has only numbers from this selection batch so I would like to keep all of ID 24's rows. Output would be:

```
ID   ID2   Code
    24   17     991
    24   18     998
    24   20     998
    52   31     991
    52   39     991
    87   66     998
    81   62     991
    81   63     991
    81   64     990
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering on grouped variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737083/filtering-on-grouped-variable)

Comment: @GuedesBF that link is a different logic as the solution showed here `subset(df, !Group %in% Group[!Activity %in% c('Act1', 'Act2')])` doesn't work there.  Also, the `all` code in that post is doing the arguments in reverse because of the logic

Answer (score 3):

Grouped by 'ID', `filter` where `all` the 'Code' are `%in%` the vector of values from 990:992 or 998

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(all(Code %in% c(990:992, 998))) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#     ID   ID2  Code
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1    24    17   991
#2    24    18   998
#3    24    20   998
#4    52    31   991
#5    52    39   991
#6    87    66   998
#7    81    62   991
#8    81    63   991
#9    81    64   990
```

---

Or can be done without grouping

```
df1 %>%
   filter(!ID %in% ID[!Code %in% c(990:992, 998)])
```

---

Or use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df1, !ID %in% ID[!Code %in% c(990:992, 998)])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
52L, 52L, 80L, 87L, 90L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 90L, 90L, 94L, 97L), 
    ID2 = c(11L, 28L, 35L, 36L, 40L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 31L, 39L, 
    45L, 66L, 67L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 69L, 70L, 74L, 82L), Code = c(994L, 
    996L, 999L, 997L, 998L, 991L, 998L, 998L, 991L, 991L, 994L, 
    998L, 995L, 991L, 991L, 990L, 997L, 998L, 994L, 996L)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```